# Multiplying all numbers in two arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript

As an exercise, I'm trying to create a function that returns the palindromic numbers resulting from multiplying three-digit numbers. As far as I can tell, the function is running through numbers correctly, however, the resulting array is incorrect. I don't need the solution to the palindrome problem...just an idea of what I might be missing. Have I run into some limitation?

```
var palindromic = function() {
var a = [];
var res = [];
for (var i = 100; i < 1000; i++) {
    a.push(i);
}
var ar = a.slice(0);
a.map(function(x) {
    for (var j = 0; j < ar.length; j++) {
        var result = x * ar[j];
        if (result.toString() ===   result.toString().split("").reverse().join("")) {
            res.push(result);
        }
    }
  })
return res;
};
```

Comment: I just noticed that when I change the function to multiply all numbers between 0 and 99 instead of 100 and 999 it works properly. ??

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it's just trying to call console.log() 810,000 times. If you comment the console.log line, it works just fine.

```
var palindromic = function() {
var a = [];
var res = [];
for (var i = 100; i < 1000; i++) {
    a.push(i);
}
var ar = a.slice(0);
a.map(function(x) {
    for (var j = 0; j < ar.length; j++) {
        var result = x * ar[j];
        //console.log(x + " : " + ar[j] + ' = ' + result);
        if (result.toString() ===   result.toString().split("").reverse().join("")) {
            res.push(result);
        }
    }
});
return res;
};

console.log(palindromic());
```

Comment: That was just to see if it was looping properly. The highest number in the array ends up being 99,999, however, the numbers should go into the 100,000s.

Comment: From [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvjPF/1/), I'm getting 906,609 as the largest. `Array.map` may not traverse in-order, so res has no guarantee of being ordered.

Comment: Similar to Tom, if I run this code changing the initial array definition to between 900 to < 1000, I get the following numbers, all in the 100,000s: 819918, 824428, 819918, 906609, 824428, 886688, 861168, 888888, 861168, 888888, 886688, 906609

Comment: It worked for me as well when I changed the array definition. Do you know why that is? The 100 to < 1000 version, even when sorted, doesn't contain numbers larger than 99,999.

Comment: I'm confused on that assertion - [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvjPF/1/) clearly logs 906,609 as the largest, which I believe is the correct answer to the question "what is the largest palindrome number less than 1,000,000". How are you compiling this? Node, browser, website?